# REACT DataTable error - Parameter 'row' implicity has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, datatable

I am seeing the TypeScript error `'Parameter 'row' implicitly has an 'any' type'` in my React datatable component, which occur when I declare this code in column selector, value row is highlighted with red.

```
Parameter 'row' implicitly has an 'any' type.
     8 |         {
     9 |             name: 'Year',
  > 10 |             selector: row => row.year,
       |                       ^^^
    11 |         },
    12 |     ];
```

This is the code

```
const columns = [
        {
            name: 'Title',
            selector: row => row.title,
        },
        {
            name: 'Year',
            selector: row => row.year,
        },
    ];
```

I am a newbie in react. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching about `implicity has an 'any' type` I got the answer and this is the example code.

```
const columns = [
    {
        name: 'Title',
        selector: (row:any) => row.title
    },
    {
        name: 'Year',
        selector: (row:any) => row.year
    },
];
```

That's it, just put `row` inside parenthesis and add value of `any`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling typescript where you're going to be using columns so it implicitly things that `row` is any

You could do something like this

```
const buildColumns = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  columns: { name: string; selector: (row: T) => string }[]
) => {
  return columns;
};

buildColumns<{ title: string; body: string }>([
  { name: "Title", selector: (row) => row.title },
  { name: "Body", selector: (row) => row.body },
  //                          ^? (parameter) row: { title: string; body: string; }

  { name: "Prop missing", selector: (row) => row.propMissing },
]);
```

It's essentially a wrapper function for helping you type rows (you could also make it a prop so you can directly pass columns as a prop to the datatable)

Also if you don't have an explicit type declaration for your row you can do `buildColumns<typeof rows[number]>`

- `typeof row` -> gets the type of the array
- `typeof row[number]` -> gets the type of a single element of the array